# Volatile variables in GWT client code

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, memory

This is **not** about volatile variable is java, it is about **how** volatile variables are handled by **GWT compiler** while generating JavaScript code.

I have been working on GWT for a while and I know the client side java code is converted to JavaScript during compilation. In java, to read/write a volatile variable is a atomic operation since it has to be read/write from/to main memory.

But after the code is converted to JavaScript by the GWT compiler, how does this behavior change? For what I know JavaScript code runs in browser, so how volatile is the volatile variable?

Since I am not so engrossed in GWT internals, I am posting this question on SO. Any help in explaining the answer is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT will not generate concurrent code, so it does not matter which operations are atomic. Concurrent code in the browser would have to use web workers, and they don't use traditional memory sharing, which means volatile can't really be translated to anything in JavaScript.